# Comparing $X_\text{red}^2$ statistics for cosmological models

Tags: cosmology, statistics, galaxy-rotation-curve

I'm evaluating a cosmological model which competes with ΛCDM. I have charted the $Χ_{red}^2$ and $R^2$ statistics for the sample of galaxies from [McGaugh et al (2001)](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0001277v1) for my model and ΛCDM.  Each galaxy has between 10 and 20 data points, so there's not a lot of data for individual galaxies.

**So here's the problem:** How do you compare a collection of $Χ_{red}^2$ statistics?  In the chart below, you can see that a few galaxies that don't match either model have the ability to distort the average.  $R^2$ on the other hand, appears to weight each galaxy sample the same.  My instincts are that $R^2$ seems like a more fair metric, but you never see them in astrophysical journals.  It seems like $Χ^2$ or $Χ_{red}^2$ is the only statistic that's taken seriously.  Both models have two fitting parameters.  So which metric is correct for comparing the two models?
[image]

Comment: Hi Donald - I took out the stuff about your model being better than ΛCDM because it's not really relevant to the question as far as I can tell, and it might bias people toward thinking this violates our non-mainstream policy (though I believe the question is fine).

Comment: Sure.  Thanks.  I'm just interested in the issue of statistics, so it's probably for the better.

Comment: Do you (and the table) mean the reduced $\chi^2$? If so, why are they (and you presumably to follow suit) misprinting it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  I have seen this notation in several documents I've read; using the subscript to indicate that it's the reduced version of the chi-squared test.  Is this not acceptable?

Comment: That aside, I was wondering if there wasn't a more recent and (more pointedly) better data set (2001 is a long time go in the current observational era). There are [a lot of citations to the McGaugh paper](http://arxiv.org/cits/astro-ph/0001277), and some of them look (by title) to report on more recent data.

Comment: I'd call it really sloppy or lazy typesetting, myself. It's not a insurmountable problem but it bothers me. I started to edit the post to "fix" it before I realized that would make the title and body inconsistent with the table.

Comment: "I was wondering if thee wasn't a more recent"  Funny you should say that.  Apparently McGaugh and Vera are the go-to guy/gal for this kind of data.  This is the best he had (I asked him personally).  If you know of another (more recent) expert on the subject, I would take the data gladly.

Comment: "I'd call it really sloppy or lazy typesetting, myself." - I'm not the expert here, I'm assuming the guys at Wikipedia are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit.  If this isn't right, I'd like to know.  In the mean time, is there any chance of getting an answer to the original question?